# Unable to identify cause of Evaluation Error on Scheduled Suitescript

Tags: syntax-error, netsuite, suitescript

Morning All, Braindead newbie coming up
I've got a Suitescript that I can't load into Netsuite - something is missing that I can't put my finger on

So far I have only used an evaluation tool that gave the all clear, but the Suitescript Debugger has found an error that I can't locate the cause for

```
/**
@NApiVersion 2.0
@NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */
define(['N/task', 'N/runtime'], function(task, runtime) {

    /**
     * Reschedules the current script and returns the ID of the reschedule task
     */
    function rescheduleCurrentScript() {
        var scheduledScriptTask = task.create({
            taskType: task.TaskType.SCHEDULED_SCRIPT
        });
        scheduledScriptTask.scriptId = runtime.getCurrentScript().id;
        scheduledScriptTask.deploymentId = runtime.getCurrentScript().deploymentId;
        return scheduledScriptTask.submit();
    }

    function execute(context) {

        // Do stuff

var myPurchaseOrderSearch = s.create({
    transaction.type: 'purchaseorder',
    columns: [{
            name: 'transaction.internalid',
            summary: COUNT
        }],
    filters: [{
        name: 'transaction.mainline',
        operator: 'is',
        values: ['T']
    }, {
        name: "transaction.trandate",
        operator: "within",
        values: ["previousoneyear"]
    }]
});

myPurchaseOrderSearch.run().each(function (result) {

    var CountPO = parseInt(result.getValue({
        "name": "transaction.internalid",
        "summary": s.Summary.COUNT
    }), 10);

    return true;
});

return results;

    var SetDaysBtwn = (365/ CountPO).toFixed(2);
    nlapiSetFieldValue('custentity81', SetDaysBtwn);
            }
        }
    }

            // Check remaining usage and reschedule if necessary
            if (runtime.getCurrentScript().getRemainingUsage() < 100) {
                var taskId = rescheduleCurrentScript();
                log.audit("Rescheduling status: " + task.checkStatus(taskId));
                return;
            }
        }

    return {
        execute: execute
    };
});
```

Sorry to be the jerk who uploads his whole script, but this is returning error: "missing : after property id (adhoc$-1$debugger.user#25)" and being a moron I can't pin it down anywhere. If anyone can help, would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error just inside your `myPurchaseOrderSearch`. The `transaction.type` property name is invalid. It should just be `type`.

I'm not sure what you use to write your code, but FWIW using a proper IDE will help easily identify errors like this. I copied and pasted your code into WebStorm and it immediately highlighted the error in bright red.

Comment: Thanks for your help @erictgrubaugh, you're right my code writing has been very dodgy, I've downloaded WebStorm and will stick to that moving forward